# knockout binding partially work

Tags: binding, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Here's the HTML code of PartialView returned by the server upon AJAX call:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: CoverQuotesViewModel">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected" /></td>
        <td  ><input type="text"  data-bind="value: Label, enable: IsSelected" /></td>        
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

then the binding is applied:

```
$.ajax("getSelectedQuote", {
    data: ko.toJSON({ model: self.selectedQuote, model1: formData }),
    }),
    type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {

    $("#custom").html(result);

    ko.applyBindings(self.selectedQuote, $("#covers")[0]);
    }
});
```

I can see my table being populated with the checkboxes properly checked or not. However for unchecked checkboxes, the corresponding input is not greyed out (disabled). If I manually uncheck a checkbox though, the input gets disabled.

So why the 'enable' property is not bound at the beginning ?

**EDIT**

The MVC Model class:

```
 public class CoverQuoteViewModel
{
    public CoverQuoteViewModel()
    {
        Childs = new List<CoverQuoteViewModel>();
    }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsChoice { get; set; }
    public bool IsComposite { get; set; }
    public decimal YearPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal BiannualPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal QuarterPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal MonthPrice { get; set; }

    public List<CoverQuoteViewModel> Childs { get; private set; }
    public CoverQuoteViewModel SelectedCoverQuote { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT**

Returned JSON data

```
var initialData = { "Quotes":
[{ "ProductName": null, "MonthPrice": 0, "QuarterPrice": 0, "BiannualPrice": 0, "YearPrice": 0, "CoverQuotesViewModel":

[{ "ProductName": null, "Label": "Première Assistance 24h/24 (GRATUITE)", "IsVisible":    true, "IsMandatory": true, "IsSelected": true, "IsChoice": false,   "IsComposite": false, "YearPrice": 0.97, "BiannualPrice": 0.49, "QuarterPrice": 0.25, "MonthPrice": 0.08, "Childs": [], "SelectedCoverQuote": null },
{ "ProductName": null, "Label": "Assistance PLUS 24h/24", "IsVisible": true, "IsMandatory": false, "IsSelected": false, "IsChoice": false, "IsComposite": false, "YearPrice": 36.06, "BiannualPrice": 18.22, "QuarterPrice": 9.20, "MonthPrice": 3.10, "Childs": [], "SelectedCoverQuote": null },
{ "ProductName": null, "Label": "Supplément Vol Audio", "IsVisible": true, "IsMandatory": false, "IsSelected": false, "IsChoice": false, "IsComposite": false, "YearPrice": 33.36, "BiannualPrice": 16.85, "QuarterPrice": 8.51, "MonthPrice": 2.87, "Childs": [], "SelectedCoverQuote": null }
]}]
};
```

The data is parsed like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{ var jsonData = new HtmlString(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)); }
var initialData = @jsonData;
</script>
```

and the complete ViewModel

```
$(function () {
var mvcModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);

function QuoteViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.customizeQuote = function (quote) {
        self.selectedQuote = quote;

        //remove the disable attribute on all form controls before serializing data
        $(".step").each(function () {
            $(this).find('input, select').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        //convert form data to an object 
        var formData = $('#etape').toObject();

        $.ajax("getSelectedQuote", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ model: self.selectedQuote, model1: formData }),            
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger
                $("#custom").html(result);
                $("#etape").formwizard("show", "customize");
                ko.applyBindings(self.selectedQuote, $("#covers")[0]);
            }
        });
    };

    self.addRemove = function (cover) {
        alert(cover.Label);
    };
}

var myViewModel = new QuoteViewModel();
var g = ko.mapping.fromJS(myViewModel, mvcModel);
ko.applyBindings(g);
```

});

Comment: What does your view model actually look like?

Comment: I use mapping for generating the view model, so I can't really show any code, but IsSelected is a bool property on the mvc model, so it is mapped to a function in the view model. That part works but I don't see why it is not applied from the start.

Comment: You could show the data that you map to the view model, that would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your data or view model, I'd suggest setting the value to IsSelected, so then you will be able to see what the value is. If that looks correct, then there's some other issue, but I wouldn't be surprised if the values are initially incorrect. This could be due to how you are mapping the data to the view model, though I've no way of knowing.

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: IsSelected, enable: IsSelected" /></td>
```

I'm confused as to why you are using the mapping plugin twice in your code here, once on your initial data to produce mvcModel, and once to map, well, it looks like you are mapping myViewModel onto mvcModel. Did you mean to have it that way round, because that looks incorrect?

Have you looked at `g` in the debugger before you applyBindings, and investigated what it looks like?

Comment: I know it's not ideal not to be able to show some code. I'll post the mvc model. However I did try your idea, and I've noticed that when the value is True of IsSelected is True, then it shows in the textbox as True. However if the value is False, then it shows as a blank, which is definitely why the input is not greyed out. What I don't understand is that in both my viewmodel and my mvc model, when I inspect the value of IsSelected, it is properly set to either True or False. It is a non-nullable boolean type on the server side.

Comment: actually, according to knockout documentation, null or undefined value should also be considered as False.... (actually, according to knockout documentation)  So, I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: I actually just meant show an example of the JSON that you get back. Can you add the js where you are dealing with the returned data then, and your js view model?

Comment: ok, I've added plenty of information: the json data (I had to trim it down as it was massive) and the view model

Comment: Updated my answer with more questions, and a suggestion.

Comment: I've ended up refactoring the whole thing. I think my js ViewModel was somehow not properly created. I'm still in the process of refactoring but hopefully that should solve my problem. Wait and see.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, feel free to ask a question if it's still not working!